# Understanding a Summation

Tags: combinatorics

Can someone help explain why the following holds?

$$ \sum_{j=0}^{k}\left[(k-j)\frac{a^{k-j}}{(k-j)!}\frac{(1-a)^j}{j!}\right] = \frac{a}{(k-1)!} $$

I can't quite work through this, and my teacher says it's 'trivial'.

Comment: I haven't checked the details entirely, but can you write down what you get when you apply the binomial theorem to $[(1-a) + a]^{k-1}$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\frac{1}{(k-j-1)!j!}=\frac{1}{(k-1)!}\binom{k-1}{j}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$ \sum_{j=0}^{k}\left[(k-j)\frac{a^{k-j}}{(k-j)!}\frac{(1-a)^j}{j!}\right] = \frac{a}{(k-1)!} \sum_{j=0}^{k}\left[(k-1)!\frac{a^{k-j-1}}{(k-j-1)!}\frac{(1-a)^j}{j!}\right] = \frac{a}{(k-1)!} (a+(1-a))^{k-1} = \frac{a}{(k-1)!}$$

Comment: When $j=k$, I believe this gives $(-1)!$ in the denominator.

Comment: Actually the sum can be considered from $0$ to $k-1$, since for $j=k$ the summand is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^{k}\left[\color{blue}{(k-j)}\frac{a^{k-j}}{\color{blue}{(k-j)!}}\frac{(1-a)^j}{j!}\right] 
&=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\left[\frac{\color{purple}{a^{k-j}}}{\color{green}{(k-j-1)!}}\frac{(1-a)^j}{\color{green}{j!}}\right]\\
&=\frac a{(k-1)!}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\binom{k-1}j a^{k-j-1}(1-a)^j\\
&=\frac a{(k-1)!}[a+(1-a)]^{k-1}\\
&=\frac a{(k-1)!}\qquad \blacksquare
\end{align}$$